# retrieving and storing route Map data

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, search, data-structures, maps

I am working on a project where the requirement is to retrieve map related data for a specific source and destination. On each of the future requests this already fetched information which is cached is to be used. However now if either the source or destination changes, map is to be reconstructed which is inclusive of old source and destination.

Some of my questions are:

1. which data structure to use so that searching is easy and finding all the intermediate nodes between source and destination is easy and efficient.
2. I have a limited memory resource so the luxury of having a very large DSC in the memory is not possible.

I am considering storing the route data between source and destination as a list however this might make search as a linear search which i would want to avoid at any cost. It is ok if there is some overhead in constructing the structure for storing the route information, but search must be quick and easy. I am using java as the programming language.

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

You should represent your map as a graph. Each location will have list of all the immediately next places that can be reached. This way when you are given a source and a destination you can do a DFS or a BFS to determine all the paths and all the intermediate nodes that take you from source to destination.

Since you have the routes between a given source and destination cached, next time you construct the data for a different source or destination you can try and make use of the cached data.